# Inject a panel on websites

Tags: iframe, panel

I would like to inject an iframe on the right side on a website to create a vertical panel. As "panel" I mean : it should be on the right side, cover the full visible height of the page, not be affected by scrolling, but **"push"** the website content **(as opposed to cover)**.

I tried modifying padding-right on , but it doesn't work on all websites (and only affect non-positionned elements).

It should work on any website with weird layout, e.g. http://orange.jobs/

Injection is not a problem (it's a Chrome extension).

Comment: It might help if you posted what you had so far so we could steer you in the right direction. you could use something like http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via css. To cover the full visible height and make the position of this element fixed on the site do:

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
width: 100px;
```

Try not to use

```
height: 100%;
```

as this would be rendered differently by every browser. Use top and bottom instead. You can choose a width with percentage or pixel values.

This css code could be applied to every html element.
If there are issues with positioning try to add

```
display: block;
```

or

```
display: inline-block;
```

I've added a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bhil/ygCdE/1/) for this.

Update:
To make the panel not cover the sites content, add a margin to e.g. the body tag:

```
body {
    margin-right: 100px;
}
```

The margin should be the width of your panel. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bhil/ygCdE/3/)

Comment: Hey MinecraftBhil, thanks for your reply. However, I don't want to cover the website with my website, but to "push" the website on the left.

Comment: You could add a margin to the site content. I updated the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bhil/ygCdE/3/).

Comment: As I put in the original post, adding margin/padding to the body doesn't fix it for positioned elements.